# Discarding the '\n' symbol when reading a file, python

Tags: python, parsing

I am parsing a big text file, and if I could only somehow read lines without the '\n' symbol my life would be a lot easier. For example:

```
Hello
World
```

is returned by python's `readLines()` as `{'Hello\n','World\n'}`, while I need to get `{'Hello','World'}`. Is there a way to only read printed chars?

I know it can be done using regex, but I hope there's a more simple way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: An inefficient way of doing this would be f.read().splitlines()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `rstrip()` function to eliminate trailing newlines. For your specific example:

```
In [9]: s = {'Hello\n','World\n'}

In [10]: s
Out[10]: set(['World\n', 'Hello\n'])


In [12]: for i in s:
   ....:     print i
World

Hello


In [13]: for i in s:
   ....:     print i.rstrip()

World
Hello
```

More information here: http://docs.python.org/library/string.html

You might consider getting rid of the newline as you read the file:

```
with open('data.txt') as infp:
   for line in infp:
       line = line.rstrip()
       # rest of processing
```

Comment: just an FYI, rstrip() also removes any trailing whitespaces.

Comment: You can change it to `rstrip('\n')` in that case

Comment: @Kamal Thanks for pointing out the default behavior, you are right, and this is helpful. The pointer to the docs provided shows that one can also specify a specific character to remove.

Comment: `rstrip('\r\n')` is even better if you're not on Windows, where `\r\n` will be converted to `\n` automatically.

Comment: @NiklasB. I came up with a similar problem but not while reading text files, problem was on windows if you run your program on command prompt(cmd) then also the input from input() method adds '\r\n' to it, while this doesn't happens if you're using IDLE(on windows).

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('test_file.txt') as f:
    my_list = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
```

If you don't want to store the data, and just want to print (or do whatever you want to) the results you can do:

```
with open('test_file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.rstrip() #or do whatever you want to
```

Comment: Just a fyi, if the file is big this may use up a lot of memory as it's storing all of it in my_list (similar to `readlines()`). OP mentioned a big file .. just something to consider

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I added a case, where OP can just print the results or do whatever he wishes.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove newline with slicing also:

```
s = "Hello\n"  
print s[:-1]  
"Hello"
```